# Unable to access the Docker registry from Oracle Cloud

Tags: docker, docker-registry, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, podman

I have an Oracle Cloud instance with Podman on it.  I try pulling an Alpine image and get a timeout error.  The Oracle documentation doesn't mention any steps required to access the registry.  I did attempt to authenticate to the registry and got a timeout from that as well.

I have ports 22 and 443 open for TCP ingress on my security list.

My subnet's egress rule is open to all protocols for CIDR 0.0.0.0/0

ANSWERING MY OWN QUESTION:  I needed to create a NAT Gateway giving my private subnet access to the internet.

https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Network/Tasks/NATgateway.htm#NAT_Gateway

What can I do to debug this?

```
Trying to pull docker.io/library/alpine:latest...
Error: initializing source docker://alpine:latest: pinging container registry registry-1.docker.io: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp 3.216.34.172:443: i/o timeout
```

Comment: You need to check your egress rules. You are trying to establish and outbound connection which is failing.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I should have mentioned that my subnet's egress rule is open to all protocols for CIDR 0.0.0.0/0

Answer (score 0):

I needed to create a NAT Gateway giving my private subnet access to the internet.  It is working now.